# Visual Studio C# - Console outputs incorrect string

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I run my program and open a file it prints the following text in the console:

```
    File opened successfully
    System.Linq.Enumerable+<TakeIterator>d__25`1[System.Byte]
```

The first line is correct, but the second line is the one I don't understand. What's intended to happen is that it's supposed to read the first 4 bytes of the file and turn it into a string to print to the console so I can see that it reads the file header correctly. The expected output in this situation would be "MThd", which is the file type identifier.

Here is the code I have for creating the string:

```
if(fileName != null)
{
    byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
    string header = fileBytes.Take(4).ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(header);
}
```

Comment: Could you show us `fileName` object code?

Comment: An array of 4 bytes doesn't become a string just using ToString(). ToString when there is no override of its default implementation returns the name of the class.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect a text file, use `ReadAllText` instead of `ReadAllBytes`.
If you want to read a stream of bytes and interpret that as a string, use the appropriate decoding method, for example

```
var header = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileBytes.Take(4));
```

With today's multi-byte character sets, it is no longer guaranteed that a certain number of bytes corresponds to a certain number of characters. This is only reliable if you can stick to the ASCII encoding.

```
var header = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(fileBytes.Take(4));
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that he was using bytes.

Answer (score 0):

byte[].Take() seems to return something of type

``` System.Linq.Enumerable+<TakeIterator>d__25``1[System.Byte] ```

which looks like cannot be converted to a string directly.

Try iterating through it and writing (strings) of its components to the console instead.

Comment: Well, its direct conversion `ToString()` succeeds. It gives, "System.Linq.Enumerable+<TakeIterator>d__25`1[System.Byte]". That's pretty much what one would expect. In general, `ToString()` gives a representation of the type.